# Très and Trop. What is the difference?

Tags: grammaire

What is the difference between trop and très and when should I use each one of them ?

Comment: Please say what you have found when looking them up in a dictionary and explain why what you found did not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Très** means *very*

**Trop** means *too much*, implying a negative effect

It's the same usage as in english (in general) :

> This tea is very hot.    =    Ce thé est très chaud.
>
> This tea is too hot.     =    Ce thé est trop chaud.

In the first sentence, this is just a neutral statement.

In the second sentence, it is implied that you can't drink the tea.

Answer (score 0):

"*Très*" amplifies the following adjective, you can translate it to "*very*" :

"*Je suis très content*" -> "*I'm very happy*".

"*Trop*" on the other hand means that the following adjective is so important that it's too much :

"*J'ai trop mangé*" -> "*I've eaten too much*"